# Wrap a list to the right

Tags: html, css

If i had a list like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>Alex</li>
  <li>James</li>
  <li>Thomas</li>
  <li>Is</li>
  <li>Asking</li>
  <li>Questions</li>
  <li>On</li>
  <li>Stackoverflow</li>
</ul>
```

The default will be displayed like:

```
* Alex   
* James
* Thomas
* Is
* Asking
* Questions
* On
* Stackoverflow
```

What CSS would i use to get it to display like:

```
* Alex     * Questions
* James    * On
* Thomas   * Stackoverflow
* Is
* Asking
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: There's an interesting article on A List Apart on this very topic: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Comment: Looks interesting, i'll give it a tyr. Thanks @Jamie Dixon

Comment: @Jamie Dixon - great suggestion, unfortunately I need to keep these in the order I stated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**For modern browsers**

```
ul{
    -ms-column-count: 2;
    -o-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -khtml-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    }
```

Comment: nice, didn't know about `column-count` - here's a fiddle to go with: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/zRwZM/

Comment: I'll roll with this for newer (better!) browsers and use @Jamie Dixon suggestion for older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like set `width` for every `<li>` and lost order of elements, here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dpXz2/

```
li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
}

ul{
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to keep these in the order I stated, so this method doesnt work. Thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

Afaik this is not possible with CSS2.
Especially if you want to keep the order like you mentioned it.

However there is a jQuery Plugin that does exactly what you descripted.

http://www.christianyates.com/blog/mmm-geeky/multi-column-lists-jquery-alternative-method

Comment: Hmmm... its an option. I'm trying to keep jQuery to a minimum.

Comment: The result is similar to Nikhil Bhandari post but it also works for older browsers (e.g. IE7 or IE8)